# Missing default-gems file......when installing Ruby

Tags: ruby

Thank you in advance for any help.  I am new to this and am struggling a bit to piece it all together!
i have followed 'createdbypete's guide to installing Ruby on Mac OS X (I have Lion) http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/ and it has worked really well until:

```
brew install rbenv-default-gems
echo "bundler\n" >> "~/.rbenv/default-gems"
```

When I then get the error code:
**-bash: ~/.rbenv/default-gems: No such file or directory**

Have I missed some setting?  Can't find any information that anyone has had the same problem.

Thank ou

Comment: was `brew install rbenv-default-gems` ran successfully, as the error you have given is coming form second command with `echo`?

Comment: yes it was run without problem

Comment: well it should have created a `~/.rbenv` folder, if it didn't and you're sure that the brew installed successfully you can resolve the error with `mkdir ~/.rbenv` followed by re-running your second command.

Comment: thank you for replying - it did create that folder but I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

I had the .rbenv directory.  I wonder if that echo command should be run without quotes around ~/.rbenv/default-gems